# What is the verb for officially removing a judge from his office?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for officially removing a judge? "Impeach" does not seem correct unless the judicial position is an elected one.

To much derision, an American politician recently stated an opinion of a judge: "He should be disrobed." That was a comical misuse. Perhaps "disrobed" was used as analogous to a priest being "defrocked".

Is there a word for this? Or, must we circumlocute?

Comment: *Impeach* is, in fact, the correct term in the US, but this will vary by country. Which country are you asking about?

Comment: Yes, Federal judges can be impeached (through Congress). The more mundane expression is: *remove from the bench or office*.

Comment: If you are looking for a single word that will cover all the possible ways of removing judges, throughout the English-speaking world, you probably won't find it. In discussing such matters, one will usually need to either use the jurisdiction-specific term for the specific procedure that one has in mind, or just, as Lambie suggested, say vaguely *remove from the bench/office*.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using "impeach" is not that the judicial position must be an elected one; as has been pointed out, holders of positions to which one is appointed (such as federal judges or cabinet secretaries) can also be *impeached*.

The reason "impeach" does not work is that being *impeached* is like being *indicted*: while it may result in a trial, it does not guarantee either conviction or the subsequent penalty.

As the example of Donald Trump shows, one may be *impeached* more than once, and yet still not be removed from office.  It is therefore necessary to use a phrase, although one has a number of options depending on how emphatic or dramatic one wants to be (e.g., "he should **resign his position**", "he should be **removed from office**", "he should be **thrown off the bench**"; etc.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The term you're looking for is "remove from office" or "remove from the bench." While "impeach" is commonly associated with removing officials from office, including judges, it's not exclusively reserved for elected positions. In the United States, federal judges can be impeached and removed from office for "high crimes and misdemeanors" by the House of Representatives and then tried by the Senate. In some jurisdictions, the process may be different, but "impeachment" is still the term used for the removal of judges from office. So, while "impeach" may seem politically charged or associated with elected positions, it is indeed the correct term for the removal of judges in many contexts.

Comment: @Lambie maybe the downvoter suspected something fishy (see comments about AI on ELL)?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh dear, this was BEFORE I realized all zzz's answers are AI/